# Many to zero or one relationship

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework-6

I have an entity/table `purchases`. This table has a `customerId`.
I have another table `customers`. This table has `customerId`.

A single customer can have multiple purchases. But this DB is only a view/representation of the main database. Which mean customers may or may not be present. But purchase if present will always have `customerId`. Which may not have a corresponding customer in the table yet.

I want to read `Purchases` using EF6 with customer information if present or just null.

How do I set this up in EF6?

As soon as I add customerId/Customer to purchases EF creates a foreign key and prevent insert of purchases where the customer is not present. I want them two tables to be independent and only populate customer in purchases if present.

Any ideas?

Comment: Well, if you have non-null customerids, but no customer record with that customerid - then you can't define a relationship in the database (and therefore EF). So as you have alluded to, you need to keep them independent with no relationship. Then you would need to do a LEFT JOIN from purchases to customers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the `customerId` field in the `purchase` table Nullable.

If you're using EF Code First approach:

```
public int? CustomerId { get; set; }
public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
```

Otherwise, change it in the database schema and reload your EF model:

```
ALTER TABLE purchase ALTER COLUMN customerId INT NULL
```

Of course, if you're not using INT as the type for ID, change it appropriately.

Comment: @ravish.hacker If that is the case, you shouldn't have any problems with inserting Purchases with empty customerId. You're missing something. Show us the entity class for Purchase and the DB schema for the table.

Comment: hmm.. maybe I did not specify that. All of my purchases data has a customer ID. For all the rows. But its the customers I do not have. And that's why it is failing. Because I am adding a purchase with customer id which doesn't exist. 
populating of these two tables is async so I cannot guarantee the order.

Comment: @ravish.hacker I don't understand your problem. Is the code throwing an exception when purchases are getting mapped due to missing customer in the customer table OR you can't add purchases without a customer id? Because you stated this: 'As soon as I add customerId/Customer to purchases EF creates a foreign key and prevent insert of purchases where the customer is not present'. If the problem is the second one, you should be able to add new entries with null value for customerId without any problem.